# "the" with subjects in subject-verb inversion

Tags: definite-articles, subjects, subject-verb-inversion

Explanation of what subjects we can use in subject-verb inversion:

From an answer to [“Here he comes”, “Here comes he” : The order of pronoun and verb in inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246050/here-he-comes-here-comes-he-the-order-of-pronoun-and-verb-in-inversion/246081#246081):

> **1.** *On the corner is a cafe*. – correct because “a cafe” is new information (due to using “a”) and, therefore, can be transported to the end of the sentence where it receives the most emphasis
>
> **2.** *Here comes he*. – odd (not idiomatic) because “he” is in a very prominent position at the end of the sentence. This position would normally be reserved for new entities. But the fact that we are using a pronoun here means that we must already have been talking about this man in the previous discourse.

---

Examples which contradict the explanation:

[wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Directive_inversion):

> **3.** *Out of the tree fell the squirrel*.
>
> **4.** *After the speeches came the toasts*.

From a textbook:

> **5.** *The door opened and in came the doctor*.
>
> **6.** *As soon as I let go of the string, up went the balloon, high into the sky*.

---

Following the explanation above:

The fact that we are using "*the*" with "*squirrel*", "*toasts*", "*doctor*" and "*balloon*" means that we must already have been talking about these subjects in the previous discourse. Hence we can't place them in a very prominent position at the end of the sentences, as in 3.-6.

But since 3.-6. are correct, then is the explanation given at the beginning of the post wrong?

Comment: If you read on, the person who quoted 'Here comes he' stated that it is _not_ an idiomatic sentence; we would say 'Here comes Bob', but 'Here he comes' when the name isn't mentioned. 'Out of the tree fell the squirrel' strikes me as unlikely too. In an inverted sentence I would expect _a squirrel_, implying that what fell out was a surprise.

Comment: Kate Bunting, in my text: "_Here comes he. – odd_". In your text: "_Here comes he. – not idiomatic_". Why do you think the difference between "_odd_" and "_not idiomatic_" is so important? Thanks!

Comment: I thought you were quoting it as though you had been told it was correct, but that _you_ thought it was odd. Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: The explanation at the top is one reason for subject-verb inversion. It is not the only reason.

Comment: @KateBunting Your first comment is relevant. Why not post an answer around that?

Comment: 4. 'After the speeches came the toasts.' probably uses 'the' in the 'expected/typically associated' not 'already mentioned' sense. 'Would you like to come with us to hear Pavaroni sing? Can you afford the entry fee?' / 'The doctor' is otherwise idiomatic, not specifying. / 3 and 6 do provide counterexamples, merely done for stylistic effect (literary and/or enhanced sentence ordering).

Comment: Out of the tree fell the squirrel.  After the speeches came the toasts. Could also be: a squirrel and a toast. English must have a determiner unless it's a word that can do without one. "Down from the sky rained great wealth."

Answer (score 2):

You ignored the *usually*'s etc in the original post.

In terms of "the doctor" and "the speeches", the definite article "the" doesn't indicate that those people/things were talked about before. It just means that people already know that they exist.

After  squirrels and balloons, I feel the key word that you missed is the "*usually*". There other reasons for using inversion. Accentuating  items that previously been mentioned isn't banned by that post. (But using a pronoun is double okward because pronouns understate).

Comment: On Google Books I can find examples such as "Still further east, in the town of Stark, lived **the** family of John Spencer" and "To the east of these lived **the** Hokiai", where inversion is introducing a specific/unique thing not referred to before, using "the".