# "Here am I" vs "here I am"

Tags: word-usage, archaicisms

Is my understanding correct that *here am I* is just an archaic form of saying *here I am*? That is what Google seems to tell me.

Comment: What makes you doubt the references you've found?

Comment: I am the doubter type of guy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Here he comes", "Here comes he" : The order of pronoun and verb in inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246050/here-he-comes-here-comes-he-the-order-of-pronoun-and-verb-in-inversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here am I is not always archaic: To express astonishment or disbelief, you can say "Here am I, a professor of physics, and you are telling me that gravity is caused by magnets!"

Or "Here are the apples that I said I would buy for you."

"Here" is an adverb. The phenomenon is called "Adverb Fronting Inversion"

Random Idea English at http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2014/09/exploring-inversion-and-fronting.html has a good explanation

> Inversion and fronting
>
> Inversion is often used in connection with fronting. Sometimes fronting involves inversion, often it doesn't. Sometimes that inversion is obligatory, sometimes it isn't.
>
> •  Fronting of a negative adverb, with obligatory inversion.
>
> He had never seen such a wonderful sunset. (standard word order)
>
> Never had he seen such a wonderful sunset. (fronted with inversion)
>
> •  Fronting of a prepositional phrase, with optional inversion
>   A large dog lay in front of the fireplace. (standard word order)
>
> In front of the fireplace, lay a large dog. (fronted with inversion)
>
> In front of the fireplace, a large dog was chewing a bone. (fronted, no inversion)
>
> •  Fronting of wh-clause - here inversion is not possible
>
> I've no idea why she's late. (standard word order)
>
> Why she's late, I've no idea. (fronted, no inversion)
>
> The commonest uses are “so do I” and “neither do I”.

The other instances are usually archaic (when this form was commoner) or poetic:

"Dearly did I love her"

"Eagerly will I go to the king's palace."